# ng-repeat across list angularjs of only values

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of countries

```
countryList = ["India", "Australia", "USA", "Germany"]
```

I do I `ng-repeat` across above list.....it is not a dictionary.
I tried using `ng-repeat="item in countryList track by $index"` but it gave me back error. Some body can tell me why it is happening ?

Please find console log
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Bipv4Pub%7D%7D&p4=%7Bipv4Pub%7D%7D
    at Error (native)
    at https://jiodns.jio.com/js/angular.min.js:6:417
    at ib.throwError (https://jiodns.jio.com/js/angular.min.js:191:165)
    at ib.object (https://jiodns.jio.com/js/angular.min.js:200:324)
    at ib.primary (https://jiodns.jio.com/js/angular.min.js:190:207)
    at ib.unary (https://jiodns.jio.com/js/angular.min.js:197:478)
    at ib.multiplicative (https://jiodns.jio.com/js/angular.min.js:197:205)
    at ib.additive (https://jiodns.jio.com/js/angular.min.js:197:63)
    at ib.relational (https://jiodns.jio.com/js/angular.min.js:196:435)
    at ib.equality (https://jiodns.jio.com/js/angular.min.js:196:291)

Comment: Can you share your error (in console) please ?

Comment: Show us your ng-repeat code

Comment: where is your countryList array? Are you sure it is inside the scope?

Comment: `Syntax Error: Token '{'`. I guess ng-repeat is not used properly.

Comment: @Vaelyr Yes ng-repeat was not used properly by me.....I fixed it....Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Is countryList available on the scope ? If yes, there shouldn't be any problem. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14183/

```
  $scope.countryList = ["India", "Australia", "USA", "Germany"]


  <div ng-repeat="country in countryList">
      <p>{{country}}</p>
  </div>
```